# Why is the title suggestion text not capitalized correctly?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [As a site about EL&U, should we maintain correct grammar, punctuation, etc. throughout the site?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2137/as-a-site-about-elu-should-we-maintain-correct-grammar-punctuation-etc-thro)

Come on, it's an English language Q&A!

> what's your english language usage question? be specific.

Comment: It's a test. You passed.