# Title placeholder is rather ironic

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is the title suggestion text not capitalized correctly?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2490/why-is-the-title-suggestion-text-not-capitalized-correctly)

I recently noticed that the enter-title-placeholder reads:

[image]

Upon further examination, the phrase lacks capitals at the beginning of the sentence, as well as after the question mark.

Comment: There's quite a nice chain of closed-as-dupe questions about this, both here and on the meta-meta, and not a single satisfactory answer anywhere. :/

Comment: I think it's because the entire SE uses a single template. Whoever designed the template either thought that lower-case looked hip, or else didn't want to deal with worrying about case on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: @J.R., except a designer shouldn't have to worry about case, other than perhaps making a heading all-caps. Whoever writes the text should write it with the correct casing, and then nobody ever needs to think about it again. If they really did it just to make it look cool, that's just... bad. Really bad.

Comment: @Marthaª: I'm not endorsing the design decision, I'm just explaining why I think things are the way they are. I don't think it would be hard to capitalize the _W_ in "What's" or the _B_ in "Be." But the _E_ in "English" might be trickier. (I mean, I wouldn't capitalize the _C_ in ["cooking"](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).)